# How to have a www.myapp.com and a my.myapp.com for a MERN stack app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I have recently finished building an app. Currently the domain is [www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com) (not really just for example purposes)

the [www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com) is hosting the landing page and the dashboard is accessed throught [www.myapp.com/dashboard](http://www.myapp.com/dashboard)

I would like to host my dashboard at my.myapp.com and only the landing pages on [www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com)

I am Using the MERN stack and have my domain through Godaddy while using Heroku to serve my files. Do I need to purchase a new domain at my.myapp.com ? or Do I need to have 2 heroku servers? One for [www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com) and another for my.myapp.com?

Also Is my.myapp.com considered a subdomain of [www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com) ? I find these terminologies confusing and cant find an answer anywhere.

Here is another example. I work out at lifetime fitness. They have a website at [www.lifetime.life](http://www.lifetime.life) and after you login it takes you to my.lifetime.life

Are these two separate servers?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution.

Here is my setup.

I have purchased my domain from godaddy

my domain is [www.happyNewYears.com](http://www.happyNewYears.com) (not really)
(Ill get to the my.happyNewYears.com part in just a second)

I am using Heroku to deploy my react app.

Now I have finished my react app, its a MERN stack app. The file structure is in this image

[image]

You can see this has a PROD1 folder, which has all my backend logic, and a frontendReact folder that contains the react build.

When I deploy this to heroku I currently am deploying it all on one server at [www.HappyNewYears.com](http://www.HappyNewYears.com)

My goal is to have [www.HappyNewYears.com](http://www.HappyNewYears.com) be the landing page, and the dashboard to be at my.HappyNewYears.com

So in Heroku, select your app and go to settings. Once in settings there is a button to "Add domain"

Click this and you will see this pop up

[image]

Make sure you are adding the [www.happyNewYears.com](http://www.happyNewYears.com)

not just happyNewYears.com

This will return you a heroku link something like this, ( patience Im getting to the my.happyNewYears.com part)

```
curly-pineapple-6s74zofl10g9mlq7w7532opf.herokudns.com
```

Note: This Link is pointing to [www.HappyNewYears.com](http://www.HappyNewYears.com) because when I added the domain in Heroku I added it with the www. so this link always points to the www.

Now you are going to go Back to your godaddy account and find the domain you are wanting to work with, In my case its [www.happyNewYears.com](http://www.happyNewYears.com)

[image]

Now Select DNS And find the area of the page that looks like this below.

You will notice that you can Add a DNS record. Click the button to add,

This will pop up a few Inputs like this below,

Make your type a CNAME, Im still setting up the www. so lets make the name part www

[image]

Then in the value input you are going to post your curly-pineapple-6s74zofl10g9mlq7w7532opf.herokudns.com link

Note: Remember this link was created in Heroku with "add Domain" when we added it we did it with the www. so it was [www.HappyNewYears.com](http://www.HappyNewYears.com)

[image]

Now when we add this CNAME to godaddy give it a sec for the DNS to update. I usually happens pretty quick but can take 2 days (Usually happens in 5 minutes for me)

Now our app should be displayed at [www.HappyNewYears.com](http://www.HappyNewYears.com)

Now, Lets deploy our app to my.HappyNewYears.com

Lets Go back to Heroku, select our app and select Add Domain again,

Instead of putting [www.HappyNewYears.com](http://www.HappyNewYears.com), now we are going to put my.HappyNewYears.com

This will return you another Heroku link something like this

```
marine-herring-n2ti9mlz8inb3o1x3qhaualu.herokudns.com
```

Now go back to your GoDaddy account and select the domain again and go to DNS.

Once we are back in DNS settings we are going to Add another DNS record. This will be a type of CNAME but instead of putting www for the Name, we are going to put my (this can be whatever you want). In the value we are going to paste our new Heroku link we just created for my.HappyNewYears.com

In my case it was this link

```
marine-herring-n2ti9mlz8inb3o1x3qhaualu.herokudns.com
```

[image]

Now Once you add this CNAME record give it a second to update in godaddy.

You will notice your app is now hosted at my.HappyNewYears.com (or whatever your domain is ex. my.yourWebsite.com)

Now this is hosting entire app on my.happyNewYears.com and [www.happyNewYears.com](http://www.happyNewYears.com)

Note:

If you want your landing to on [www.HappyNewYears.com](http://www.HappyNewYears.com) and the Dashboard my.HappyNewYears.com you will need two seperate apps on Heroku. So you need to build an app that has only landing logic, and seperate all your dashboard logic into another app.

So have one Heroku build with just Landing and one Heroku build with your dashboard stuff.

Go to your Heroku app with the landing build and "add Domain" with the www. and follow steps above to update the CNAME in godaddy

This will host your landing

Now for Dashboard go to Heroku and Build your app with just dashboard logic.
Go into this App and "Add Domain" with the my.HappyNewYears.com and follow steps above to update the CNAME in godaddy.

There are also obvious other steps with your routing like changing all your dashboard urls to my.HappyNewYears.com and In your Google Oauth settings or whichever API you use it all needs to be aimed at my.HappyNewYears.com instead of your [www.HappyNewYears.com](http://www.HappyNewYears.com)

Hope this helps It can be confusing and alot of people starting out Coding will be getting domains from godaddy and using Heroku for servers just due the amount of content on the web from those two giants